# Cannot read lines in a file using boost filesystem

Tags: c++, boost

I have a cpp file which contains of:

```
#include <QApplication>

int/**/ main(int /*c*/,char**v)
{/*

*/
    QApplication app(c,v);//
//
    return app.exec();

/**/

}
```

I'm opening this file:

```
boost::filesystem3::path file("C:\\Users\\Art\\Desktop\\six_lines.txt");
boost::filesystem3::ifstream fin(file);

    if (fin)
    {
        std::string read_line;
        while (getline(fin,read_line))//here I'd hope to read just one line
        {


        }
    }
```

Unfortunately getline(fin,read_line) is executed just once (file exists). Why?

Comment: That Qt .cpp file is of *no* use whatsoever in this question, so I removed it.

Comment: @Xeo it is of use just to show that getline should be executed more than once.

Comment: Oh, was that .cpp file actually the `"six_lines.txt"` file? If so, sorry.

Comment: Does it read the entire files? Is it a new-line issue?

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because I wonder how come `std::string` is qualified while `getline` isn't.

Comment: @jrok: the getline() function is found because it is looked up in the namespace(s) of its paraneter.

Comment: @smallB: If after `getline` executes only once `read_line` is still empty than see my answer below.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Right, thanks. ADL hasnn't fully nested in my brain just yet :)

Comment: @DietmarKühl getline it seem like it reads just the last character from this file.

Comment: What's the encoding of your text file? Try creating a test file with Notepad.